# Create DropDownListFor with database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want create DropDownListFor in ASP.NET MVC with database and I have a problem "Compiler Error Message: CS1955: Non-invocable member 'TreeViewModel.TreeItems' cannot be used like a method."

ViewModel:

```
public class TreeViewModel
    {
        public List<DTree> leafs { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Wybierz gałąź")]
        public int SelectedRootId { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> TreeItems
        {
            get { return new SelectList(leafs, "Id", "Name"); }
        }
    }
```

View:

```
@model Apka.ViewModels.TreeViewModel
@using (Html.BeginForm("Exercise", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedRootId, Model.TreeItems());

    <input type="submit" value="przycisk"/>
}
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Exercise()
        {
            var dt = new DbAccess();
            var listTree = dt.GetAllTree();
            var list = new List<DTree>();

            foreach (var row in listTree)
            {
                list.Add(
                    new DTree
                    {
                        Id = row.Id,
                        Name = row.Name,
                        ParentId = (Convert.ToInt32(row.ParentId) != 0) ? Convert.ToInt32(row.ParentId) : (int?)null
                    });
            }

            TreeViewModel tvm = new TreeViewModel();
            tvm.leafs = list;
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Exercise(TreeViewModel tree)
        {
            var id = tree.SelectedRootId;
            ViewBag.ID = id;
            return View();
        }
```

Comment: `Model.TreeItems()` should be `Model.TreeItems`

Comment: after change is this same

Comment: Can you give me the reference of DTree? I am trying to implement it on a fiddler. Or better yet add you fiddler in here( https://dotnetfiddle.net/CsMvc ) and post the link?

Answer (score 1):

TreeItems is a member of TreeViewModel, not a method, so you can't call it with parenthesis like a method.

In your view, try changing the line

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedRootId, Model.TreeItems());
```

to

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedRootId, Model.TreeItems);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just pass the model `tvm`

```
return View(tvm)
```

[here demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/e8jvBM)

Answer (score 0):

Hi there are mainly  two things we need to correct in the above code:

1. change this line  `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedRootId, Model.TreeItems());` like this  `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedRootId, Model.TreeItems);`

**Hint :** removed parenthesis from TreeItems since it is not a method

2.Pass the viewmodel to the exercise view

**Corrected code:**

```
public ActionResult Exercise()
        {
            var dt = new DbAccess();
            var listTree = dt.GetAllTree();
            var list = new List<DTree>();

            foreach (var row in listTree)
            {
                list.Add(
                    new DTree
                    {
                        Id = row.Id,
                        Name = row.Name,
                        ParentId = (Convert.ToInt32(row.ParentId) != 0) ? Convert.ToInt32(row.ParentId) : (int?)null
                    });
            }

            TreeViewModel tvm = new TreeViewModel();
            tvm.leafs = list;

            //passed the model 
            return View(tvm );
        }
```

Hope it was helpful

Thanks

Karthik